# Filling multidimensionnal array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a little problem in JavaScript.

I need to get an array width date as keys and events as values.

In PHP I would do something like this :

```
$var = new array();
Loop
$var[$date][] = $event;
End loop
```

Do you know what I mean ?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: No, I don't really know what you mean. But I took a guess and posted an answer. If that doesn't answer your question, please comment explaining your problem more.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, you can create a data structure like that this way:

```
var events = {
    '2009-09-09': [],
    '2010-10-10': [],
    '2011-11-11': []
};
```

The `events = { ... }` is an object literal in javascript. Objects in javscript act very much like hashes with properties as keys, so this is essentially going to act as a hash keyed on dates. Each date is initialized with an empty array.

And you can fill it up with events like this

```
events[date].push(event);
```

If you don't know the dates ahead of time, you can dynamically fill the hash. So, you'd start with just an empty hash:

```
var events = {};
```

Then you'd check for the date key every time you go to add an event, like this:

```
if (!(date in events)) events[date] = [];
events[date].push(event);
```

The `date in events` checks to see if the key exists, and the `!` negates it. So if the date key *does not* exist, it initializes the date key with an empty array. Then it pushes the event for that date as normal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To explain me better : I'm fetching in a loop dates that are in an object. I want to fill all dates with multiple events, nor, I don't know how I can add element to an array without specifying any key, like in PHP $events[$date][] = $event;

Comment: @ben heh i figured... but part of me was wondering if I had missed the point of the question completely!  One of those days : )

Comment: @PierreLechelle, I updated my answer to reflect that. Does that work for you?

Comment: @PierreLechelle, I think I finally am understanding what you want, and re-wrote my answer yet again. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Ben ! You're awesome ! Thanks for your time and your many rewrite ! I've success ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript key-value mappings are handled by `Object`s.  An empty object is just `{}`.  You can do this sort of thing like (note that var is a reserved word in Javascript so I can't copy your example exactly):

```
var variable = {};
var date_list = [1,2,3];
var event_list = [4,5,6];
for (i in date_list){
    var key = date_list[i];
    var value = event_list[i];
    variable[key] = value;
}

// variable now contains: {1:4, 2:5, 3:6}

console.log(variable[1]);
// prints 4
```

EDIT: That's the basic syntax.  If you want to have an array for each key, just do something like that but with arrays instead of numbers in event_list.  For example:

```
my_dates = {'2011': [1,2,3], '2010': [6,7,8]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an element to a list you can use the `push` javascript method of array objects...

```
events_by_date = {};
...
for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    if (!events_by_date[events[i].date]) {
        // This is the first event on this date
        // so create the list
        events_by_date[events[i].date] = [];
    }
    // Add the event to the list of events in that date
    events_by_date[events[i].date].push(events[i]);
}
```